# Customize log entry for AWS ELB for real user IP

Tags: nginx, logging, amazon-elb, cloudflare

I would like to change the logging format for AWS ELB, in order to log the real user IP.

My current server setup contains multiple layers of proxies as followed:

CloudFlare -> AWS ELB -> Nginx (EC2)

With proper nginx modules, I am able to obtain the real client IP in the log of my EC2 instance using the X-Forwarded-For header. However, I am not able to find a way to configure AWS ELB to log the IP in X-Forwarded-For which is set by CloudFlare.

I would like to customize the log entry generated by AWS ELB to log the real user IP, so I can analyze the full log in the future, rather than collect the logs from each EC2 instance.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote emails to AWS technical support and they responded that currently ELB does not support such configuration at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [CF-Connecting-IP header which is set by CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) in your nginx real_ip configuration.

For example:

```
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

ELB doesn't seem to *have* any option to do this. You're almost certainly going to have to aggregate your logs yourself.

Comment: I am already using this for my nginx(ec2) instance, which works great. My question is how to log the real ip in ELB instead (which should log all connections across EC2 instances)

Comment: ELB doesn't seem to _have_ any option to do this. You're almost certainly going to have to aggregate your logs yourself.

Comment: I also received an official answer that ELB doesn't support such configuration. Would you like to create another answer so I could mark it? Thanks

Comment: the question is, who stops using ELB directly and fake CF-Connecting-IP header